# How to in-place-upgrade Windows 2012 R2 connection broker to 2016/2019?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, rds, windows-server-2019

I have a 2012R2 RDS infrastructure. 
Connection Broker, Webinterface, Gateway Manager are running on the same machine with Windows 2012 R2. 
Session Hosts are both 2012 R2 and 2019. 
Database and licensing are installed on a DC.

Now I wanted to upgrade the 2012 R2 machines to 2019. But after the upgrade finished and I rebooted the machine, Server Manager can't connect to the connection broker. 
It's always written: "connect to rds connection broker" but it stuck there... no error, no message at the error log. 
I have tried 2019 upgrade and 2016 upgrade, in both cases the same frustrating result.

Fortunately I can rollback to 2012 R2 and DCs Server Manager again can find the RDS collection.

So did anybody managed to successfully performed a in-place-upgrade from 2012 R2 to 2019? 
Are there some kind of pitfalls I may have forgotten?

EDIT: 
I have tried to get a list of all RDS servers via powershell but I get the following PS Error:

```
The value cannot be null.
Parameter name: format
+ CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [Get-RDMSJoinedNode], ArgumentNullException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: System.ArgumentNullException, Microsoft.RemoteDesktopServices.Management.Cmdlets.GetRDJoinedNodeCommand
+ PSComputerName: localhost
```

The same command issued on the same server **before** the in-place-upgrade gives me a fine list of all RD Servers (CB, Web Access, Gateway and Session Hosts).

Comment: hi, it seems that an microsoft help exists for it. try  `https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/upgrade-to-rds`  in my work place we usually use the option to install from scratch

Comment: Thanks, but there is just written what I have done. "Remove all CB from HA setup, except one, perform in place upgrade on them". Well I tried it but RDS doesn't work and doesn't show up in server manager.

Comment: as told, we do this for our customers obly via a new farm by fresh setup